# Does type assertion change the value in go?

Tags: go, interface

Go newbie here.

I have a map where the key arguments should be `[]string`.

However, if I try to use the value directly `arguments := m["arguments"]` it doesn't seem to be the right type. When used later to append to another slice with `arguments...` I get `Cannot use 'arguments' (type interface{}) as type []string`.

I fixed this by chaning the assignment to a type check `arguments, _ := m["arguments"].([]string)`. That works, but I'm not sure why. Is [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) doing conversion as well?

The full example is below:

```
import (
    "github.com/fatih/structs"
    "strings"
)

var playbookKeyDict = map[string]string{
    "Playbook": "",
    "Limit" : "--limit",
    "ExtraVars" : "--extra-vars",
}

type Playbook struct {
    Playbook string `json:"playbook" xml:"playbook" form:"playbook" query:"playbook"`
    Limit string `json:"limit" xml:"limit" form:"limit" query:"limit"`
    ExtraVars string `json:"extra-vars" xml:"extra-vars" form:"extra-vars" query:"extra-vars"`
    Arguments []string `json:"arguments" xml:"arguments" form:"arguments" query:"arguments"`
    Args []string
}

func (p *Playbook) formatArgs() {
    // is it worth iterating through directly with reflection instead of using structs import?
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246642/iterate-over-string-fields-in-struct
    m := structs.Map(p)

    // direct assignment has the wrong type?
    // arguments := m["arguments"]
    arguments, _ := m["arguments"].([]string)
    delete(m, "arguments")

    for k, v := range m {
        // Ignore non-strings and empty strings
        if val, ok := v.(string); ok && val != "" {
            key := playbookKeyDict[k]
            if key == "" {
                p.Args = append(p.Args, val)
            } else {
                p.Args = append(p.Args, playbookKeyDict[k], val)
            }
        }
    }
    p.Args = append(p.Args, arguments...)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type assertion is used to get a value wrapped around using interface.

```
m := structs.Map(p)

Map(v interface{}){}
```

Map function is actually taking interface as its argument in the case stated. It is wrapping the type which is `[]string` and its underlying value which is slice. The type can be checked using [Relection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) `reflect.TypeOf()`.

```
func TypeOf(i interface{}) Type
```

According to Russ Cox blog on [Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

> Interface values are represented as a two-word pair giving a pointer
>   to information about the type stored in the interface and a pointer to
>   the associated data.

As specified in [Golang](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) spec

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

For the error part:-

```
Cannot use 'arguments' (type interface{}) as type []string
```

We first needs to get the underlying value of type `[]string` from interface using type assertion.